# How to insert RAW Hex data from a text file?

Tags: hex, hex-editors

I'm using Hex Workshop and I needed to edit numerous data so I selected a range of HEX values and copied it to Notepad++.

I edited the values and now I need to copy it back to HEX Workshop but it seems to be a little problem. When I just CTR+C, I can't paste in HEX Workshop.

I tried using the Insert function but it will just convert everything from the TXT file to HEX. That's not what I want - the content on TXt file is already in HEX. I just want to simply paste and overwrite the values in HEX Workshop.

Same as I would if I edited it manually byte by byte in HEX editor but I just want to copy these values form TXT and paste it in HEX.

I know I can edit in HEX editor ofc, but I needed to do some other stuff around these HEX values.

Answer (score 0):

I use the open source tool [Be.HexEditor](https://hexbox.sourceforge.net/) for pasting text hex values into a file as hex:

1. Copy hex code to the clipboard
2. Open target file to insert hex code
3. Move the cursor to the the desired position to insert hex
4. Click `Edit > Paste Hex`
5. Save

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind. Hex Editor Neo did the trick.